# Why can't my users delete their comment?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, comments, sql-delete

I have created a website with a comments page for users to delete the comments that they upload. However the delete comment button appears however it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone shed some light on this for me please?

```
<?php
    require_once("checklog.php");
    include_once("nihome_start_logged.php");
    require_once("nifunctions.php");?>

<div id="navigation">
<ul class="container">
    <li><a href='nihome.php'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="nihome.php#content"> Search for your service</a></li>
    <li><a href='nisalons.php' class='button'>Salons and Reviews</a></li>
     <li><a href='nichangepassword.php' class='button'>Change Password</a></li>
     <li><a href='nilogout.php' class='button'>Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<?php

    if (!$db_server){
            die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error($db_server));
            $db_status = "not connected";
    }else{
        //Capture form data, if anything was submitted
        if (isset($_GET['salonid']) and ($_GET['salonid'] != '')){
            $salonid = clean_string($db_server, $_GET['salonid']);

            //code to delete comments
            if($db_server){
                mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
                mysqli_query($db_server, "DELETE FROM comments WHERE username = '$username' and salonid = '$salonid' ");
                $message= "<p> Comment deleted </p>";   


            //If connected, get Salons from database and write out
            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
            $query = "SELECT ID, salon_name, address, postcode, telephone, email, website FROM salon WHERE ID=$salonid";
            $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
            if (!$result) die("Query failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $str_result .= "<h2>" . $row[ 'salon_name'] . "</h2>";
                $str_result .= "<p>" . $row['address'] . "</p>";
                $str_result .= "<p>" . $row['postcode'] . "</p>";
                $str_result .= "<p>" . $row['telephone'] . "</p>";
                $str_result .= "<p>" . $row['email'] . "</p>";
                $str_result .= "<p>" . $row['website'] . "</p>";
            }
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }else{
            $str_result = "<h2>No salon selected</h2>";

        }

    }
    echo $str_result;
?>

<?php 

if(trim($_POST['submit']) == "Submit comment"){

    //Get any submitted comments and insert
    $comment = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['comment']);
    if ($comment != '') {
        $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
        if ($name == "") $error .= "<p class='error'>You must write a review and upload an image!</p>";
        $originalname=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
        $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
        if ($type=="image/jpeg")  $type=".jpeg"; //if true change 
        else if ($type=="image/jpg") $type=".jpg";// if not true check this one
        else if ($type=="image/png") $type=".png";
        $name=uniqid() . $type;

        $path="images/" . $name;
        $tempname=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
        $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
        //Error checking
        if ($size >1000000) $error .= "<p class='error'>Your image file is to big, it have to be less than 200 mb</p>";
        if ($error=="") {
            if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $path)){

                $uploadquery="INSERT INTO comments (comment, imagename, salonID, userID) VALUES ('$comment', '$path', $salonid, ". $_SESSION['userID'].")";
                mysqli_query($db_server,$uploadquery) or die ("Insert failed " . mysqli_error($db_server) . " " . $uploadquery);
                $message= "<h2>Thanks for your comment!</h2><p>Your upload was succesful</p>";

            }
        }
    }

}

//Print out existing comment
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.ID WHERE salonID=$salonid"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        if ($_SESSION['username'] == $row['username']){
            $deletecomment = "<input class='delete comment' type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Delete comment'/>";
        }else{
            $deletecomment = " ";
        }
        $str_comments .= "<p><span class='comments'>" . $row['Username'] ." : " . $row['comment'] . "</span></p>";
        $str_comments .="<p><img src='" . $row['imagename'] ."'  /></p>";
        $str_comments .= $deletecomment ;
}


mysqli_free_result($result);

?>  
<div id="form">
<table><form id='review' action='salonpage.php?salonid=<?php echo $salonid; ?>' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<th><h2> Do you want to review the service you recieved?</h2></th>
<tr><td><textarea name="comment" rows="6" cols="40">Write something here!</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='file' name='photo' accept='image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png'/></td></tr>
<br/>
<tr><td><input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Submit comment' /></td></tr>
</form></table>
<?php echo $error;
    echo $message;?></div>

<h2> Reviews and comments </h2>
<?php echo $str_comments; ?>
<?php mysqli_close($db_server); ?>

<div id='footer'>
<a href="privacy.php">Privacy Statement</a>
<a href="accessibility.php">Accessibility Statement</a>
</div>
<?php include_once("nihome_end.php"); ?>
```

Comment: if($db_server){
                mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
                mysqli_query($db_server, "DELETE FROM comments WHERE username = '$username' and salonid = '$salonid' ");
                $message= "<p> Comment deleted </p>";

Comment: @user3095683 As you can clearly see, code in comments is unreadable; please use the 'edit' link and put that into your question

Comment: sorry! new to stackoverflow too..

Comment: What error are you getting? and what's the result?

Comment: Well thats my problem, I'm not actually getting any errors, I get a button come up beneath the comment saying 'delete comment' yet when I click it nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

From you code, you used form-submit-button to delete the record -- and it's stored in `$str_comments`.

You need 

`<form .....>
<?php echo $str_comments ?>
</form>`

Because the submit-button needs form to live in.

Answer (score 0):

#1 I suggest you start using classes.

#2 if you're using mysqli(i stands for improved) why are you doing things the "old way"?

#3 a classfull example

```
$drop = new CLASS_NAME_GOES_HERE;
$drop->drop_comment($id,$un);

class CLASS_NAME_GOES_HERE {

private $con; // only access from this class and its children and dont need $ anymore
function __construct() { // constructor function
        $this->con = new mysqli(DB,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or
                die('Cannot connect.');
}

function drop_comment($id,$un) {
    $sql= "DELETE FROM upload WHERE id = ? AND username = ?";

    if($try = $this->con->prepare($sql)) {
        $try->bind_param('ss', $id, $un);
        if($try->execute()) return true; 
    }
}//END FUNCTION
}//end class
```